# Sitecore Query Notation in X-Path Builder

Tags: xpath, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am having an issue with Sitecore's XPath Query utility in the developer centre, I have selected to use 'Sitecore Query Notation' over XPath as I want to return field values of items I am selecting. I cannot seem to get it to return field values like I want to (for example path, and price field on the items)

I am running the query below:

```
select @@path
from /sitecore/content/Product Repositories/*
```

And I get the following message:

```
End of string expected at position 6.
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this to not return results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Syntax **select @@path from** can be used with Sitecore rocks query analyzer, but can't be used within Sitecore Developer center or by Sitecore query API.

So your query in developer center should be like:

```
/sitecore/content/Product Repositories/*
```

In code, you can retrieve items based on your query then fetch the fields you need

```cs
string query = "/sitecore/content/Product Repositories/*"; 
Item[] items = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query);

foreach(Item item in items )
{
    var path = item.Paths.FullPath;
    ...

}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for the answer, do you happen to know the reason why the select statement was not included for use in the Developer Centre?

Comment: This syntax (Select, Update, Delete, Create) is developed for Sitecore Rocks, i dont know exactly why it was not included in Developer center, but i would guess its way to risky to be able to run CRUD operations from within Developer Center inside sitecore desktop

Comment: Also, here is a link of what you can do with Sitecore rocks quries: http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/07/Sitecore-Rocks-Queries.aspx

Comment: thanks, I did already manage to get it working in Sitecore rocks, I was just hoping that it was available in the Dev Centre as well as it would mean other users of the system could run queries. Giving you the tick now, good answer

Answer (score 0):

The space is the issue. It should read:

```
select @@path
from /sitecore/content/#Product Repositories#/*
```

Comment: I have tried `select @@path from /sitecore/content/#Product Repositories#/*` and I still get the same error message, strangely though when I do the same command in sitecore rocks I get the data I am looking for, is this an issue/limitation with the XPath Builder tool in the Developer Centre?

Comment: I'm not aware of any issue using xpath. What version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: Version 7.2, it looks like Ahmed has the answer to why it will not work.